# boost thread not running whilst main application is in a while loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, sleep

I'm fairly new to using boost threads.  I've almost got something running, but have hit a stumbling block:  Any help would be appreciated.

I have an VC++ (VS2010 Windows Forms) application.  In the near future this needs to be ported to C++ and Linux, so I am using the boost libraries for things like threading to "ease" the port.

I have a worker function in a class performing some i/o:

```
void myClass::doIO{

    while (!boolKillthread){


    //do some work

    //sleep thread 
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(333));
    }
}
```

which is kicked on in a boost thread:

```
boost::thread m_MyThread;
m_MyThread = boost::thread(boost::bind(&myClass::doIO));
```

This is working just fine, the i/o ports are being polled, and are calling back into the parent class perfectly.  BUT:

I have an other function that needs to wait on the doIO thread to perform some work, so I have a function with code on the lines of:

```
while (myClass.IsWorkDone() == true){

    //hang a around a while

    //lines commented out below have been tried, but don't resolve the problem
    //boost::this_thread::yield();
    //boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(50));
    //boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(50));

}
```

The problem is that as soon as my code enters the while loop, the boost thread doIO halts - almost as if it were not running in it's own thread!  I have tried inserting sleeps & yields as per the commented out lines above, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

---

Thanks for the responses all: Yes, the (pseudocode) "IsWorkDone" is just returning a variable, so I understand (and have now tried) using a boost::mutex::scoped_lock to update that variable, so we have something like

```
bool myWorkIsDone = false;

bool myClass::IsWorkDone{ return myWorkIsDone; }



void myClass::doIO{

    while (!boolKillthread){


    //do some work
    if (SomeCondition){
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(myMutex);
        myWorkIsDone = true;
    }

    //sleep thread 
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for(boost::chrono::milliseconds(333));
    }
}
```

that's fine, but the point is that (unless I'm missing something obvious, which is entirely likely) the thread does not appear to be running when my main code is in the loop

while (myClass.IsWorkDone() == true){

```
    //hang a around a while

}
```

as the IDE will stop on a breakpoint in doIO normally, but NOT when execution is in the above while loop.

There's not really any more code (of relevance) to add - it should be pretty simple, but it doesn't work!

Comment: Any mutex in IO operations?

Comment: I had to guess about the problem in my answer because there's not enough code here to know. `::boost::thread` most definitely always creates a new thread of execution. So your code must be doing something wrong.

Comment: Can you forcibly break into the other thread? BTW, `boolKillthread` will have the same problem is `myWorkIsDone`, but that's likely not your problem. Your other thread is obviously blocking on something. The obvious choice is that it's blocking on IO, but maybe it's waiting on a mutex or something. With the 'do some work' all commented out like that this thread should work just fine. And I bet if you remove all the work in the original code, it will.

Comment: @Omnifarious:  Thanks for the help.  I have reaplced mymain doIO with a dummy function to test the theory that something else is blocking - which does indeed seem to be the case. With the striped down doIO function the threads seem to run OK.  (My challenge now is to work out what's - but that's another story!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `IsWorkDone` look like? Does it look like this:

```
 bool IsWorkDone() const { return workdone_; }
```

Because if it does, that's you're problem. You need to use a mutex to wrap access to `workdone_`. That's shared state, and shared state needs a mutex. The compiler is probably reading the variable at the top of the loop and never bothering to read it again. After all, as far as it can tell, there's no reason at all for it to change, so there's no point in reading it again.

And even if it does read it again, the CPU has a nice cache line holding it that's likely never getting flushed, and so you're just reading that instead.

Oh, and when you set it, that needs a mutex too.

Making it an `::std::atomic<bool>` is actually a better idea, but I'm guessing you don't have that yet.

Comment: OK, understood about the mutex, thanks, I'll try it. However - if I place a breakpoint in my doIO function, it gets hit as it should during normal (UI is idle) execution, but not when the code is the while (myClass.IsWorkDone() == true){ ... } loop.

Comment: No need for mutex, volatile will do the trick instead. `vloatile` keyword instructs compiler that variable can be changed from outside thus can't be cached aggressively or optimized away.

Comment: Uh, no. volatile is the wrong thing for multi-threading. It will do the right thing in Visual Studio, but not in GCC. And since he's porting, introducing VS dependencies is the wrong way to go. std::atomic is a better idea, but of course that requires VS to be updated to 2012.

Comment: @Lazin: That is a very wrong answer. Dangerously wrong because it seems superficially correct. It completely fails to address the cache line issue. And yes, the other commenter is correct, `::std::atomic` will work, but I assumed no C++11 since the OP was using `::boost::thread`.

Comment: @Zippy: You haven't shown enough code for me to tell you what's wrong there.

Comment: Thanks for the responses all:  Yes, the (pseudocode) "IsWorkDone" is just returning a variable, so I understand (and have now tried) using a boost::mutex::scoped_lock to update that variable, so:

Comment: Question updated so I could pop in alittle more pseudo code... thanks all.

Comment: @Omnifarious Let me share some thoughts about this. I think this is compiler optimization problem (you was right), not the cache problem. I don't know the case when processor can hold cache line unchanged infinitely if corresponding memory cell was updated. Cache coherency protocol invalidate corresponding cache lines after any update. Actual write can be delayed by the write buffer but as far as I know - not infinitely. Correct me if I wrong.

Comment: @Lazin: I believe there are processors that have a loose enough cache coherency protocol that the value will never propagate without some sort of synchronization instruction. I think, for example, that the DEC Alpha was such a processor. But in general you're right. That will usually eventually work. I just really prefer code that's obviously correct to code that's subtly correct.